Why does including a linking path in my GCC compile command with libcurl break compilation?
My goal is to be able to use cJSON and libcurl for a current C project. I am able to use libcurl WITHOUT any linkers/linker path options. When I add the linker path to my GCC compile options, I get a bunch of “unreferenced functions” and other related issues to libcurl not existing.
This is an issue because I NEED to have a linker path in my GCC compile command for cJSON to work. This is my commands:
Error producing command:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

gcc -I/home/arch/coding/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include -lcurl \
    -L/home/arch/coding/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib -lcjson \
    main.c -o gitgetn

One that compiles errorless:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

gcc -I/home/arch/coding/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include -lcurl \
    main.c -o gitgetn

I’ve tried re-erranging the order of commands with the issue causing one and some versions just give me a BUNCH more errors. This command just breaks libcurl entirely:
gcc main.c  -I/home/arch/coding/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include \
    -lcurl -L/home/arch/coding/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib -lcjson \
    -o gitgetn


Put the -L options before the -l options on the command line.

What errors do you get? Copy paste them into the question.

Where does the 'compiles errorless' version obtain the cJSON library from?  Where do you think the libraries are installed?  What does ldd gitgetn from the errorless build report?

You seem to have several substantially different versions of libraries you are trying to use scattered around your machine. Including or not including a link path determines which version gets used.

You should probably put the -L and -l options after main.c (or main.o) if the GCC linker defaults to -Wl,--as-needed (as mentioned in an answer to the question linked in the comment above) and put the -I options before main.c.
